# Differing search results between Twilio web search and Ruby API helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, twilio

I'm getting different results between the searches I run on on twilio.com and the searches I run through the Ruby gem helper.

Here's a sample search:

[image: Searching the 19428 zip code on Twilio's website]

Here's a search with the same zip code in a Rails console, returning an empty array:

```
> @twilio_client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local.list({in_postal_code: "19428"})
=> []
```

These searches were conducted less than a minute apart.

Is this an issue with the REST API, the Ruby helper gem, or my search query?

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

The code you're using is correct to retrieve phone numbers restricted to a postal code and I can see why you would expect it to match up with the search on Twilio.com. In our search we're actually doing the lookup a bit differently. You can create an experience similar to ours by using a different [set of filters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=oct2015&utm_campaign=stackathon#local-get-advanced-filters) to retrieve phone numbers.

```
@numbers = @client.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local.list(
   near_lat_long: '40.6928,-73.9903',
   distance: '5'
)
```

Since phone numbers within a postal code can be sparse we can ensure results by expanding our search to be near the location a user searches for.